# Two-dimensional array of different types

Tags: java, data-structures

I want to create a two-dimensional array in which I want to store records from the database. So lets say that the first is of type `int` and the second of type `String` (here I am describing just one record so basically types of db columns). How can I do it? Is an array the right data structure for that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Arrays can only contain one type. If that type happens to be `Object` then it can store `Object` and any of its sub-types, but that doesn't really sound like what you're trying to accomplish here.

It sounds like what you're describing is a 2D array to store database information, with each element in the array being a column in one of the rows. This **isn't** an array of records, it's an array of column data.

Instead, just store a one-dimensional array of records, where each element of the array is a reference to the entire DB row.

Comment: I am sorry but I am not sure what do you mean by: "each element of the array is a reference to the entire DB row". The entire DB row is made up of two columns of different types, string and int. How can I store it in one array?

Comment: What are you using to access the database? There must be an object that represents a row in a table. Then that row must have methods you can call to access the column data in that row. Whatever object wraps the database row is what you need to store in your array. I mean, that's essentially what a database table is - an array of rows.

Answer (score 15):

I am not sure I am following, but you might be looking for a [`Map<Integer,String>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html). or `Map<Integer,List<String>>`. [have a look on [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html), and [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)]

`Map` allows association of the key [`Integer`] to the value [`String` or `List`].

`Map` also allows fast lookup of key, and its attached value.

(*) You should use `Map<Integer,List<String>>` if you want to attach more then one `String` per `Integer`, or alternatively you can use apache commons [`MultiMap`](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiMap.html)

Comment: Map<Integer,String> if you this than java not allow record for duplicate Integer.

Comment: @yogeshprajapata You could use one of Guava's or Apache's `MultiMap`s to allow this, though.

Comment: @Jeffrey  but you have not mentioned here that you are talking about Gauvas's Map.

Answer (score 5):

You can do the same thing with the help of this

```
Object[][] o = new Object[10][10];

o[0][0] = 1;
o[0][1] ="hello";

System.out.println(o[0][0]);
System.out.println(o[0][1]);
```

Comment: Hey Yogesh, I am trying to do the same with o[0][0] = an array of Strings and o[0][1] = a String. this does not work for me, should this work for me?

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to have one column of String data and another column of int data, this is what you can consider doing:

Declare a 2 dimensional String array

```
String[][] words = new String[][];
```

Your first column can contain all the String data. The second column can have the numeric data but in the form of a String. You may want to use the Integer.toString() and Integer.parseInt() methods to do this

```
words[index][index] = Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(args));
```

I'm not sure what exactly you hope to achieve but you may consider modifying this snippet to suit your needs