# Can Multidimensional Arrays how two different types in them within java

Tags: java, arrays

Can a multidimensional array in java have two types like a string and double in it?

Like: {name, num},{name, num}

Comment: Use an Array of an Object which contains the 2 elemnts. That's what Objects are for.

Comment: You *could* do this with a 2D `Object` array and a bunch of casting. But just because you *can* do a thing doesn't mean you *should* do a thing. See above comment.

Comment: You don't want an example of bad programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zoyd has it right, that this should be done with a class. Here's a more complete example.

```
class MyClass 
{
    private String name;
    private int num;

    public MyClass(String name, int num)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.num = num;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public int getNum()
    {
        return num;
    }
}


MyClass[] array = new MyClass[5];
array[0] = new MyClass("name1", 5);
array[1] = new MyClass("name2", 8);
...
```

If name or num ever need to change after original creation, then you can add setters for them.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, this is normally done with a class.

```
class C {
public String name;
public int num;
}
```

(later)

```
C[] myArray = new C[5];
myArray[3] = new C();
myArray[3].name = "Ford";
myArray[3].num = 42;
```

name and num should typically be made private and accessed with getters and setters, but this is beyond the point.

Comment: Wouldnt that be at position (5,5)? Also how do I set the name and num?

Comment: This probably needs to be a 1d array now. The class acts as a dimension.

Comment: new c[5][5] creates a 2 dimensional array that spans from (0,0) to (4,4) and therefore contains 25 elements. I made it this way because you wanted a "multidimensional" array. If you only need one dimension, you can drop the second [5]. I don't understand what you mean by "Wouldnt that be at position (5,5)".

Comment: A couple things.  1: class names should be capitalized.  2: Making this a class removes the need for a multi-dimensional array.

Comment: @tucker19 > added example showing how to set the name and num.

Comment: Even just seeing the answer to this question makes me shudder.  This may be correct, but it is a terrible design.  Please OP rethink your design!

Answer (score 0):

```
    int row=10;
    int col=10;

    Object [][] objArray=new Object[row][col];

    objArray[0][0]=181818;
    objArray[0][1]="Hello String";

    System.out.println(objArray[0][0]);     
    System.out.println(objArray[0][1]);
```

You can use Object for that.

Plus you need to search before you post it. There is already answer here. [Two-dimensional array of different types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10063354/two-dimensional-array-of-different-types)

Answer (score 0):

This solution has nothing to do with arrays, but if you've got `{name, num}, {name, num}` data, you might want to consider using a map.

```
Map<String, Double> map = new HashMap<String, Double>();

Double valueX = 123.456;
Double valueY = 654.321;
map.put("nameX", valueX);
map.put("nameY", valueY);

Double valueX = c.get("name");
for(String name:c.keySet()) {
   System.out.println("name:"+name+"\tvalue:"+c.get(name));
}
```